# linear independence on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m$ are polynomials in $p_m(\Bbb F)$ such that $p_j(2)=0$ for each $j$. I want to prove that ($p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m)$ is not linearly independent in $P_m(\Bbb F)$

Now this seem to be quite apparent with there being any number  of ways of writing zero as a linea sum of vectors with $\Bbb F=2$. But I don't know ho to prove this for F in general. Is the F=2 case sufficient?

Comment: Given the way it's worded, the field $\mathbb{F}$ is arbitrary, so it is not sufficient to prove it for a specific field.

Comment: One possibility is to use a change of basis: Instead of using $x^0,x^1,\ldots,x^m$ as a basis, you might use $(x-2)^0,(x-2)^1,\ldots,(x-2)^m$ as a basis.

Comment: @hugh Does that imply that I have two zero vectors currently?

Comment: E.g x=0,2${}{}{}{}$

Comment: No. None of the polynomials have to be the zero polynomial. The hypothesis $p_j(2) = 0$ affects the coefficients of the polynomials, though it's not obvious how in the standard basis. (This is why I suggest using an alternative basis.)

Comment: That makes sense thanks. Also I would like to report my question as duplicate sorry. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210287/linear-independence-question-from-axler?rq=1